# Why fragment adjust better to different screen size as compared to activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I found below statements as an advantage of using fragments-

- Fragments are used to efficiently use the space in wider screen size.
- Fragments are used as means of solving compatibility issues when
  targetting an android application for different screen
  sizes,especially for both tablets and mobiles.

Does this mean an activity doesn't efficiently use the space in wider screen size and it does not adjust well to different screen size?Why is fragment better than activity in terms of using screen space on different screen sizes?

Comment: where did you find these statements?

Comment: @TimCastelijns http://skillgun.com/android/fragments/interview-questions-and-answers

Comment: that is completely wrong.

Comment: @VladMatvienko What is wrong?

Comment: that `fragment adjust better to different screen size as compared to activity`

Comment: Second one is not well formulated but the first one is actually true. On wider screens you can use 2 Fragments displayed at the same time when you will use them separately on a narrow screen (typically tablets vs phone). You can't do that with Activities as you can only have one Activity displayed at a time. So in this way, the statements are corrects. [See the official documentation for more info](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design)

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is, that by using Fragments, you can reuse that Fragment in different layouts, for example to put more information on a larger screen.

Most basic example would be a list where a click on an item brings you to a detail screen.

On Phones you might have seperate screens for both fragments, while on a tablet you might as well show them side-by-side.

**List Fragment:**

[image: phone screen list]

**Detail Fragment:**

[image: phone screen details]

**Tablet Screen with both Fragments next to eachother:**

[image: tablet screen showing both fragments]

*[Screenshots are taken from a project I made for my Udactity Android Developer Nanodegree]*